# Redirect script output to /dev/tty1 and also capture output to file

Tags: raspbian, linux, output, bash

I want to display text output on the console that is always displayed on a small screen ( Adafruit 2.8 Inch TFT ) on my Raspberry Pi.

The following code works for showing that text output:

```
cd /home/pi/python_test_scripts_linux && sudo nice -n -20 /home/pi/python_test_scripts_linux/test_wrapper.py > /dev/tty1
```

Now I want to capture the output in parallel with seeing it on the screen - I have tried 'tee' but that does not show text on the screen and also does not capture it to file:

```
cd /home/pi/python_test_scripts_linux && sudo nice -n -20 /home/pi/python_test_scripts_linux/test_wrapper.py | tee /dev/tty1 /tmp/capture.txt
```

How can I redirect the output of my script to `/dev/tty1` so I can see it on my screen but also capture the output to file?

UPDATE 1:

Per the answer below - I tried using 'script' - unfortunately it did not work:

```
script -c "cd /home/pi/python_test_scripts_linux && sudo nice -n -20 /home/pi/python_test_scripts_linux/test_wrapper.py > /dev/tty1" /home/pi/python_test_scripts_linux/report.html
```

UPDATE 2:

I also tried to 'tail' the output of the file that I redirected the output to into /dev/tty1, but it also did not work:

```
sudo tail -F /home/pi/python_test_scripts_linux/report.html > /dev/tty1 &
cd /home/pi/python_test_scripts_linux && sudo nice -n -20 /home/pi/python_test_scripts_linux/test_wrapper.py > /home/pi/python_test_scripts_linux/report.html
```

Comment: I think the tee command will do what you want. You can read the man page with the following command man tee. Can you try this cd /home/pi/python_test_scripts_linux && sudo nice -n -20 /home/pi/python_test_scripts_linux/test_wrapper.py | tee -a /dev/tty1 /tmp/capture.txt  or cd /home/pi/python_test_scripts_linux && sudo nice -n -20 /home/pi/python_test_scripts_linux/test_wrapper.py | tee /dev/tty1 > /tmp/capture.txt you may also want to reverse the tty and file in the last one. For what it is worth this would be easier to debug if you made the stuff before the pipe to tee ls.

Comment: this works for me ls | tee /dev/tty4  /tnp/lsout note I used ls to make debugging easier (less typing).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for the input, it did not work for Python scripts because it was buffering the output.

This allows it to work with tee:

```
python -u ./myscript.py | tee /dev/tty1 /tmp/a.txt
```